# Debugging Codeship build that runs fine with Jet

Tags: jet, codeship

How should I debug a Codeship build that runs successfully with `jet steps` locally? I make sure to run it on a fresh checkout, so it starts in the same state as Codeship. My process is:

1. Make fresh clone of repo
2. Call `jet steps --push --tag master --no-cache` (steps
   will only push for master)

Running in Codeship, the same `master` continues to fail

```
Build Error: No source files were specified
2017-08-07T13:25:59.136Z my-image build/pull had an error
```

The [docs](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/cli/) say to use `jet steps` for debugging, but what should one do when this isn't helpful?

Comment: I've also hit this occasionally - can you put your steps/services files into a gist?  Hard to say based off what you have here what it could be. Sometimes it's your local docker cache that could be masking something.

Comment: Thanks, @KellyJAndrews, but I can't publish our files. I've opened a ticket #14866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I used false assumptions.

The truth of the matter is that running local with `jets` and remotely on Codeship are very different processes. Success locally does not portend success on Codeship.

- `jet` will be successful, regardless of what `volume` configs you pass
- `jet` does not run individual steps in isolated containers, Codeship does
- `jet` will share state between `steps` and `services`, Codeship won't

Further, if you need state between `steps` and `services`, very carefully read the footnotes on the Codeship [volumes docs](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/docker-volumes/).

Comment: The two points about jet not running individual steps isolated, and sharing state is really bad. Are you sure about this is the case?